# How to do a group by count using multiple columns in R?

Tags: sql, r, group-by

In SQL I can get a count using group by like this:

```
select
  column1,
  column2,
  column3,
  count(*)
from
  table
group by
  column1,
  column2,
  column3;
```

**How is this done in R?** I have a dataframe with the ungrouped data.

---

**UPDATE**

I eventually got this to work via:

```
grouped_data <- aggregate(data, by=list(data$column1, data$column2, data$column3), FUN=length);
```

Comment: This is also very straight forward in R and has been answered many times in FAQs, on SO and around the interwebs... What have you tried so far that hasn't worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually got this to work via:

```
grouped_data <- aggregate(data, by=list(data$column1, data$column2, data$column3), FUN=length);
```

Comment: You can also explore the formula mode. Without seeing any sample data, try something like: `aggregate(. ~ column1 + column2 + column3, data, length)`. Also, it is OK to *accept* your own answer since that makes it clear to others viewing the question that there is an accepted answer available.